# WordPress gallery text link

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I am looking for a way to open a gallery slideshow images not by clicking on a thumbnail image but a text link like *Go to Gallery*.
I don't care wheter using WordPress default gallery, NextGen, Jetpack or any other gallery plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I have found a solution with NextGen Gallery.
in nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/ngglegacy/view/gallery.php
Change the following part:

```
<div id="ngg-image-<?php echo $image->pid ?>" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box" <?php echo $image->style ?> >
    <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail" >
        <a href="<?php echo nextgen_esc_url($image->imageURL) ?>"
           title="<?php echo esc_attr($image->description) ?>"
           <?php echo $image->thumbcode ?> >
            <?php if ( !$image->hidden ) { ?>
            <img title="<?php echo esc_attr($image->alttext) ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image->alttext) ?>" src="<?php echo nextgen_esc_url($image->thumbnailURL) ?>" <?php echo $image->size ?> />
            <?php } ?>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

into:

```
<div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail" >
        <a href="<?php echo nextgen_esc_url($image->imageURL) ?>"
           title="<?php echo esc_attr($image->description) ?>"
           <?php echo $image->thumbcode ?> >
            Link
        </a>
    </div>
```

After that, I am hiding the CSS-Class 'ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box', except the first child. This works well.